# C++ PizzaOrder.h and PizzaOrder.cpp How to write correct classes for my cpp file using a header file

Tags: c++, arrays, class

This is my first time asking for help on here so I would really appreciate some guidance! The assignment I have is the following:

PizzaOrder - Create a class named PizzaOrder that stores information about an order
of potentially multiple pizzas. It should contain the following:
•  A private member variable, m_order, which is an array of base type Pizza. Each pizza
saved in this array should be a Pizza object.
•  A private member variable, m_numPizzas, which tells how many Pizzas are in the order
•  Two constructors:
o  Default constructor which defaults to an order of a single small cheese Pizza.
o  Overloaded constructor that takes an integer parameter that tells how many
pizzas will be added to the order and initializes the order instance variable to an
empty array of that size.
•  Destructor
•  In addition to the constructors, provide the following methods:
o  int addPizza(Pizza pizza)— add the parameter Pizza object to the
PizzaOrder’s order member variable. Given that the order is saved as a Pizza
array, remember that once the order is full you will not be able to add more
pizzas! Implement this method to indicate that adding the additional pizza
was unsuccessful. If the addition was successful the method should return
a 1 and if unsuccessful (array is full) return -1.
o  double calcTotal() —returns the total cost of the order by adding up the
prices of each pizza in the order (hint: use the calcCost method from the Pizza
class for each Pizza object in the order array)
o  string toString() —returns a string representing this order, so that the
employee at the pizza joint can repeat the order back to you before sending it to
the kitchen. This method should begin by calling the calcTotal() method so
that the total price of the order can be displayed.

The problem I am having is how to incorporate what I have in my header file into the cpp file. I have two other parts to this assignment, one other header and cpp file that I will call in the main but this is my first time with c++ and classes in general, so I am having a really difficult time. I will include the following code that I have for some reference as to what I'm working with. I would really appreciate some advice. Thank you all!

Header File:

```
#ifndef PIZZAORDER_H
#define PIZZAORDER_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class PizzaOrder {
private:
  Pizza* m_order[];
  int m_numPizzas;

public: //constructors
  PizzaOrder(); //default
  PizzaOrder(int m_numPizzas); //overloaded
  virtual ~PizzaOrder(); //deconstructor

  //other methods, how we interact
  int addPizza(Pizza pizza); //add the parameter Pizza object to the PizzaOrder’s order member variable
  double calcTotal();
  string toString();

};

#endif
```

Cpp File:

```
#include "PizzaOrder.h"
#include "Pizza.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


  PizzaOrder::PizzaOrder(){ //default
    m_order = new Pizza*[1];
    Pizza p("small",1,0,0);
    m_order[0] = p;
  }
  PizzaOrder(int m_numPizzas){

  } //overloaded
  PizzaOrder::~PizzaOrder(){//deconstructor
    //purposefully empty
  }
  //other methods, how we interact
  int PizzaOrder::addPizza(Pizza pizza){ //add the parameter Pizza object to the PizzaOrder’s order member variable
    cout << "How many pizza?" << endl;
    int sz;
    cin >> sz;

    m_order = new Pizza[sz];
    for(int count = 0; count < sz; ++count){
      m_order = new Pizza[count];
      Pizza p(m_size, m_cheeseTop, m_pepperoniTop, m_veggieTop);
    }
  }
  double calcTotal();
  string toString();

};

#endif
```

Comment: In your question "how to incorporate what I have in my header file into the cpp file", what, exactly, does "incorporate" mean? Please be very precise.

Comment: It's called *destructor*, not *deconstructor*.

Comment: In header-files you should not use `using namespace std;` Reserve that for the cpp-files. So you should have a `std::string toString();` to fix the fix :-)

Comment: it looks like you have 2 headers, pizza and pizzaorder. You can put the class definitions in one header (for simplicity if you want), and the implementation (with constructor/function defintions of both classes) in a pizza_impl.cpp file and have a main.cpp file that #includes the pizza header. Then link them together with g++ -o pizza_impl.cpp main.cpp for separate compilation

Comment: Keep in mind cpp file will compile without main, but it won't be able to generate exe file, and no #endif for cpp files. They're for #ifndef or #ifdef, you're not using them for cpp file.

Comment: Your header part `Pizza* m_order[];` doesn't work since `Pizza` is no defined in the header (or forward declared), and second, a flexible array member ‘PizzaOrder::m_order[]’ is not part of standard C++. Did you mean `Pizza* m_order;` (after a e.g., struct Pizza; before it)?

Comment: Hello! I do have a main.cpp file that I used to test out another Pizza.h and Pizza.cpp which worked. The professor wants them as 5 separate files, so I can't unfortunately but mesh them together. Those  first ones have the pizza class that I think(?) I have to include in the pizzaorder header. I don't necessarily understand the concepts of arrays but will try your suggestion. :)

Comment: And honestly even I don't know what I mean by incorporate. The main idea is to (in the main) have the 3 pizzas that will then be added to the array. However as previously mentioned, I don't really understand arrays :/. Another problem that I don't understand is how to use the information on two headers and two cpp files to call in main.cpp? how would I call that using g++ -o ......?

Comment: @PinkOtakuGirl if you want to use header whose definitions are in separate file from your main file, you need to use separate compilation. You need to individually compile each file and then link their obj files with g++ -o main.exe main.o pizza.o (etc.) to generate their exe file. I prefer to do them in one line if the there isn't a lot of files with g++ o main.exe main.cpp pizza.cpp....etc.